# Как получить значения частот и амплитуд сигнала после прямого преобразования Фурье?

Tags: fft, обработка-сигналов

Есть сигнал (массив чисел `signal` размером N). Далее я создал массив комплексных чисел `complexArr` размером N, поместил в действительную часть комплексных чисел значения сигнала. После этого я на вход функции БПФ подаю массив `complexArr` и на выходе получаю преобразованный массив комплексных чисел `complexArrTransformed` размерности `N`.

**Вопрос:** как с помощью значений из массива `complexArrTransformed` построить спектр сигнала (т.е. как получить значение амплитуды `A` при конкретной частоте `f`)?

Comment: Сэр, амплитудный спектр это модули комплексных чисел в массиве complexArrTransformed. Соответственно, позиция в complexArrTransformed - это номер гармоники.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов т.е. чтобы получить частоту, нужно номер гармоники умножить на частоту дискретизации и поделить на N? И по поводу амплитуды: Это точно модуль комплексного числа? или все же это (2 / N) * модуль? (я где-то видел такую формулу, но не помню где)

Comment: Зачем делить на N? Вы все-таки загляните в учебник. Гугол принес http://www.vlsu.ru/fileadmin/Kadry_dlja_regiona/7/7-2-7/7-2-7-02_2013_Radiotekhnicheskie_Tsepy_i_Signaly.pdf